# Can we put numbers in IBOutlet names?

Tags: ios, iboutlet

`IBOutlet` names like `upperIconSet1View`, `upperIconSet2View;` then for views inside them `frameIconView11`, `frameIconView12`, `frameIconView13`, `frameIconView21`, `frameIconView22`

Can these names cause any problems later?

Do they conform to the naming conventions?

Any other name suggestions?

Comment: Please read [Swift Language Guide: Lexical Structure](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/LexicalStructure.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH30-ID410) section *Identifiers* - first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can put numbers in outlet names. An outlet name can be any Swift or Objective-C identifier. In both languages, any character of an identifier can be a digit except the first character. For example, this is legal (but hard to type):

```
@IBOutlet var é9: UIView!
```

However, I'm worried that you want several numbered names because you want to iterate through them in a loop, like this:

```
@IBOutlet var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet var view2: UIView!
@IBOutlet var view3: UIView!

func doSomething() {
    for i in 1 ... 3 {
        // Not real syntax
        view$i.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Although there are ways to make that work, they either require extra work to maintain, or use more advanced (confusing) APIs. If you just want to store a collection of views, make your outlet an array:

```
@IBOutlet var views: [UIView] = []

func doSomething() {
    for view in views {
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

This will show up in the storyboard/xib editor as an “outlet collection”, and you can connect it to multiple targets simultaneously.